# How to make create image when screen is touched then be able to move it

Tags: ios, touchesbegan, touchesmoved

I am trying to create a dot on the screen when it is touched and then be able to move that dot around and then ending the touch which will bring up an alert view. For the first touch and movement i have this code so far...

```
{
    UIImageView *dot =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(359,487,50,50)];
    dot.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"hockey-puck-stress-toy-superextralarge-175648.png"];
    [self.view addSubview:dot];
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    dot.center = location;
}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

The problem is that this creates a new object when moving instead of just when I first touch it. I understand why it does this, but i don't know any way to fix it. Could someone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a property in your .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic) UIImageView *dot;
```

And then just create the view if it doesn't exist and then move the property:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (!self.dot) {
        UIImageView *dot =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(359,487,50,50)];
        dot.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"hockey-puck-stress-toy-superextralarge-175648.png"];
        [self.view addSubview:dot];
    }
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    self.dot.center = location;
}
```